# How to create an expandablelistadapter with array lists dynamically in Android

Tags: android, dynamic, arraylist, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am trying to create a expandable list view with an adapter that updates the parent and child elements at runtime. I have an array list for the parent elements and an array list for the child elements. The parent is an array list of objects called 'Group' and each group has an array list of objects called 'Item'. So Group is the parent element and Item is the child element.

I currently have an expandable list view which just uses a fixed array for the strings in the parent and child elements. I need to know how to do this dynamically at runtime with array lists. Please can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Here is my expandable list view code at the moment:

```
public class ConfigAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

private Activity activity;
public String []parentList = {"parent1", "parent2", "parent3", "parent4", 
                                        "parent5", "parent6", "parent7"}; // String array for parent list text views
public String [][]childList = {
        {
            "parent1 child1", "parent1 child2", "parent1 child3", "parent1 child4"
        },
        {
            "parent2 child1", "parent2 child2"
        },
        {
            "parent3 child1", "parent3 child2"
        },
        {
            "parent4 child1", "parent4 child2", "parent4 child3"
        },
        {
            "parent5 child1", "parent5 child2", "parent5 child3"
        },
        {
            "parent6 child1"
        },
        {
            "parent7 child1", "parent7 child2", "parent7 child3"
        }

}; // String array for child list text views

public ConfigAdapter()
{
    assert "Default constructor not used." != null; // Assert to prompt not to use this constructor.
}

public ConfigAdapter(Activity refActivity) 
{
    this.activity = refActivity;
}

public void setPage(Page refPage)
{
    page = refPage;
}

public Page getPage()
{
    return page;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    LayoutInflater childLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View childView = childLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.config_child_list_view, null);
    TextView itemTextView = (TextView) childView.findViewById(R.id.configListTextView1);
    itemTextView.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
    final ViewSwitcher childViewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) childView.findViewById(R.id.configListViewSwitcher);
    final TextView dataObjectTextView = (TextView) childViewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.configListTextView2);
    dataObjectTextView.setText("99 99 999 99 9 9 999 9  9 99 99999  9999  9999");
    final EditText dataObjectEditText = (EditText) childViewSwitcher.findViewById(R.id.configEditText1);
    dataObjectEditText.setHint("hello");

    childViewSwitcher.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if(childViewSwitcher.getCurrentView() == dataObjectTextView)
            {
                childViewSwitcher.showNext();
            }

        }
    });
    {

    }

    return childView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
{
    return childList[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
{
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() 
{
    return parentList.length;
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
{
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    TextView tvParent = new TextView(activity);
    tvParent.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
    tvParent.setPadding(10, 20, 10, 20);
    tvParent.setTextSize(18);
    tvParent.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD); // Sets text to bold

    return tvParent;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() 
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
{
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What is your problem here and What help you need?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data for `ExpandableList` is populated at runtime , so what you have to do is , when you get your data at runtime , you have to load them into your `Array`s. If there is a chance of duplicate elements you have to handle that as well. When you are done loading them in your `Array`s for Parents and Childs , then you have to notify your Adapter that dataset has been changed by the following method.

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: I think that I actually need a String[] for the groups. A String[][] for items and a String[][][] for data objects which are a value associated with each item. Is it possible to do this from a data set of objects that are in array lists? I have the view in the child view with textviews next to each other that has the capability of holding an item in one and a data object in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ArrayList<String> parentList` for group, `List<ArrayList<Sring>> childList` for child.

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
{
    return childList.get(groupPosition).size();
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() 
{
    return parentList.size();
}
```